# Ionic add search input and refresher

Tags: ionic-framework, html5-apps

I using ionic to develop a app. I got into trouble when I added search input and refresher.

For keyboard, Ionic will add some class or inline style to body and ion-content on focus the search input. But there is 'overflow: visible;' on ion-content so that refresher will be uncovered.

a part of my HTML as follow:

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
    <ion-refresher
            pulling-text="refreshing~"
            refreshing-text="loadding..."
            on-refresh="doRefresh()">
    </ion-refresher>

    <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="to search...">
        </label>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

How to change HTML structure?

I used a ionic plugin [ionic-plugins-keyboard](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard).

Comment: I do not understand the problem. I made a codepen that has a search input field inside of a refresher. Is your code behaving differently? http://codepen.io/MrOnosa/pen/nmAHC

Comment: I mean because of keyboard, seemingly [ionic-plugins-keyboard](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard), so the plugin will add `overflow: visible` on `ion-content` when the search input is focused.